# How to get the id of a table in HTML and affect a function in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am creating a function in Jquery and I need the id of this table. I used inspect element on chrome. The table looks like this
[image]

how can I get the the id of this table and affect a function to it ? For example :

`var rowCount = $('#myID tr').length;`

I used the number displayed in `data-reactid`  this way

`var rowCount = $('#.0.1.1.0.0.0 tr').length;`

but it's not working. I don't think it's the id. 
I have multiple tables so I need the exact id not just `$('table')`

Any ideas please ? Thank you.

Comment: Don't use react-id as a unique ID this are custom id added by react in previous version for reconciliation . In latest version react doesn't use the same. Please have some unique ID for the same or provide unique classes to all the table added.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either jquery's `$('.inner-table').data('reactid')` or `.attr()` function. Try them if they are working. However, I am not sure if they will work with reactjs together.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting tables by CSS class might help narrow down the process for selecting the correct table. The following JQuery will select all tables with BOTH the listed classes:

```
tables = $('table.inner-table, table.upper-buttons');
```

You could (depending in the pages, layout, etc) then just get the first table like this:

```
theTable = $('table.inner-table, table.upper-buttons').first();
```

And therefore get the custom attribute thusly:

```
var rowCount = $('table.inner-table, table.upper-buttons').first().attr("#.0.1....").length;
```

... or something close to it